# Perl Date String Parsing with Time::Piece

Tags: perl, strptime

For some reason I am having a lot of trouble parsing date strings using Time::Piece.

So this works:

```
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( 'Sunday, November 4, 2012 10:25:15 PM -0000' , "%A, %B %d, %Y    %I:%M:%S %p %z" );
  print $t;
```

But this does not:

```
my $temp_time = Time::Piece->strptime('7/23/2014 5:24:22 PM', "%-m/%-d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p");
print $temp_time;
```

I have also used '%D %r' as the format string but that also does not work. Do any of you have insight as to why this might be? For reference , the hour is 1-12 (not 01-12) and the month is 1-12 (not 0-12).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
"%-m/%-d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p"
```

to

```
"%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p"
```